# How to know which platform I am using in lubuntu, ubuntu or kubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, lubuntu

I need switch script in between lubuntu, ubuntu, and kubuntu. How can I know which platform the script is running in?

Because uname/lsb_release never show different in those 3 releases

```
Lubuntu$ uname -a
Linux 3.16.0-33-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 12:19:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Lubuntu$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic

Lubuntu$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=utopic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.10"
VERSION_ID="14.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Comment: `lsb_release -a`

Comment: lsb_release -a never show different in lu/u/kubuntu system

Comment: how about `uname -a`

Comment: Are you open to using fact gathering systems like 'facter' or 'ohai'? They should be able to get the actual release.

Comment: ohai & facter they both show ubuntu only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns the desktop environment currently in use. In my case, I see `LXDE` which is the desktop environment Lubuntu currently uses. `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` returns `Lubuntu`.

Comment: This won't work if you have a server (without X installed). :/